# Retrieving data with single quote from dataset (Delphi)

Tags: database, delphi, dataset, special-characters, firedac

Currently I have something like but I'm unable to retrieve my data from the dataset when it has single quote in the data

```
procedure TForm1.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  cdsMain.FieldDefs.Add('ItemCode', ftWideString, 20);
  cdsMain.CreateDataSet;

  cdsDetail.FieldDefs.Add('ItemCode', ftWideString, 20);
  cdsDetail.FieldDefs.Add('Project', ftWideString, 20);
  cdsDetail.CreateDataSet;

  var S := '6x8''''';
  cdsMain.AppendRecord([S]);
  cdsDetail.AppendRecord([S, 'P01']);
  cdsDetail.AppendRecord([S, 'P02']);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDConnection1.Connected then
    FDConnection1.Close;
  if FDLocalSQL1.Active then
    FDLocalSQL1.Active := False;

  FDLocalSQL1.Active := True;
  FDQuery1.Open('SELECT A.ItemCode, B.Project FROM Main A INNER JOIN Detail B ON (A.ItemCode=B.ItemCode)');
end;
```

My expected result are
ItemCode  Project
6x8'   P01
6x8'   P02

The error I get when I use `var S := '6x8''''`
[image]
[Source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QybPybtRRo-LXD7B8YOYQeBJzhz_32F8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your statement _var S := '6x8''''';_ sets S to the value _6x8''_, ie. with TWO single quotes at the end. So you will never receive fields with only one single quote at the end...

Comment: @HeartWare if I set S := '6x8''', then I will get Unterminated String constant error

Comment: Where do you get that error? I don't get it on the VAR line, so if you do, then either your compiler is corrupted, or you don't enter what you think/say you enter. Try copying this and putting it into your source: _VAR S := '6x8''';_

Comment: @HeartWare still gotten the same error when I copy and paste ur code

Comment: So, at runtime. That's odd - it seems like the "AppendRecord" does something strange (in my eyes). It's not (generally) supposed to be the user that has to double-specify quotes when sending strings as parameters. It should be escaped within the routine...

Comment: What types are csdMain and cdsDetail? Which UNITs have you included (then I'll try to see if I can determine why)...

Comment: Can you make your source so that it allocates all the objects and sets all the properties in code, so I can test it out? From your code, I cannot see the links between the various class instances you are using...

Comment: @HeartWare I have included a link to download the prototype that I made at the bottom

Comment: "Access Denied"

Comment: @HeartWare now should be able to download

Comment: Yep. Will look at it in my lunch break (2 hours from now)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can deduce from the source files, there's a bug in FireDAC in this case. If I eliminate the ON clause in the SQL, it works, even with an ASCII Single-Quote (#39). If I replace the ASCII Single-Quote (#39) with the UNICODE Single-Quote (#8216) or remove it altogether, it works.

It seems like the parser for TFDLocalSQL (I think) has a bug when it tries to resolve the ON clause and there's an ASCII Single-Quote involved.

You should report the error to Embarcadero at https://quality.embarcadero.com, including your source code and an explanation.